# Priority in RascalMPL using extend

Tags: rascal

I was trying to extend a expression language in my DSL, but I get ambiguity prediction warning on the priority. How can I sort out the priority in this scenario(using extend)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, we have a module A:

```
module A

lexical Id = [a-z]+; // for the sake of completeness

syntax Exp 
    = Id
    | left Exp "+" Exp
    ;
```

and then a module B that extends it:

```
module B

extend A;

syntax Exp
    = left Exp "*" Exp
    ;
```

And now when we generate the parser we get a warning about possible ambiguity between the `*` and the `+` rule.

The first solution is to add a priority by *repeating* the original rule. This leads to this version of module B:

```
module B

extend A;

syntax Exp
    = left Exp "*" Exp
    > left Exp "+" Exp
    ;
```

The precondition is that the `+` rule must be replicated exactly, literally for this to work without introducing yet another ambiguity between the two version of the rule. This includes possible labels. So this would *not* work:

```
module B

extend A;

syntax Exp
    = left Exp "*" Exp
    > left Exp lhs "+" Exp rhs
    ;
```

This is a bit clumsy all, so there is the option to use the names of rules in priority declarations as well. For this the original rule must have a name. The module A becomes this:

```
module A

syntax Exp 
    = Id
    | left plus: Exp "+" Exp
    ;
```

and then we can write this in module B:

```
module B

extend A;

syntax Exp
    = left times:Exp "*" Exp
    > :plus // the reference to the other rule in module A
    ;
```

In short: everywhere you can write a full rule, left or right of the `>` sign, inside an associativity group, etc, you can write `:<label>` to refer to any existing labeled rule *for the same non-terminal* but possibly in a different rule or even a different extended or imported module. If you don't want to add labels, then repeating the entire rule is necessary.

Comment: The last suggestion looks cleaner, I will use that and get back to you, thanks

Comment: It worked pretty well, thanks